# Tailwind CSS: peer-checked borders are not applied when a radio button radio is selected

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have this input, type "radio", and I want to apply a larger and darker border when it is selected.

When I click, the classes are applied when I inspect, but there are no visible changes to the button.

Any idea why?

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-9lnfyy)

Here is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import "./styles/tailwind-pre-build.css";
import { useState } from 'react';

const RadioButton = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  const checkedClassNames =
    'peer-checked/yes:border-transparent peer-checked/yes:shadow-lg peer-checked/yes:border-2 peer-checked/yes:border-solid peer-checked/yes:border-neutral-600 peer-checked/yes:text-neutral-700';

  return (
    <div className="w-20">
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="id"
        onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
        className="peer/yes sr-only"
      />
      <label
        htmlFor="id"
        className={`flex justify-center items-center cursor-pointer rounded-lg text-sm border border-solid border-gray-300 px-4 h-10 text-neutral-500 focus:outline-none ${
          checked ? checkedClassNames : null
        }`}
      >
        Label
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RadioButton;
```

Comment: Sandbox has an old version of Tailwind which does not supports peer utility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already changing the state of your button and using that to add classes, then you don't need to qualify those classes using `peer`. Also, in order for you to trigger your input field's `onChange`, you need to put it inside the label. This means that you cannot use `peer` to qualify your label classes.

This is untested, but shows the basic idea:

```js
...

  const uncheckedClassNames = 
    'border border-solid border-gray-300 text-neutral-500'
  const checkedClassNames =
    'border-transparent shadow-lg border-2 border-solid border-neutral-600 text-neutral-700';

  return (
    <div className="w-20">
      <label
        htmlFor="id"
        className={`flex justify-center items-center cursor-pointer rounded-lg px-4 h-10 text-sm focus:outline-none ${
          checked ? checkedClassNames : uncheckedClassNames
        }`}
      >
        <input
          type="radio"
          id="id"
          onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
          className="sr-only"
        />
        Label
      </label>
    </div>
  );

...
```